# Can you store spare vials of blood to refill a Blood Reservoir?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

The item [Blood Reservoir of Physical Prowess](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/blood-reservoir-of-physical-prowess/) states that you can spend a minute and take 4 points of Con damage to fill it. Blood in this is prevented from decaying. However, Can you spend the minute, and take the con damage, to fill a non magical vial?

Can you then take the non magical vial and use it to fill the Reservoir at a later date, presuming the blood has not spoiled?

The reservoir states that *"When filled with the wearer’s blood, it gains powerful magic."*

It does not state that the blood needs to be fresh, and AFAIK blood can be stored close to two months without being frozen. I imagine this changes given conditions. I could not find any explicit rules on how long blood (or animal components) lasts ingame.

**Can I store spare vials of blood to refill a Blood Reservoir midday without taking the constitution damage as long as all the vials filled caused the con damage?**

Comment: Ahh, yet another question where your first thought is "what on Earth are people doing over the-- oh it's RPG.SE"

Comment: Dare I ask how you stumbled upon this then? =p

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was in the Hot Network Questions. Not totally sure, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No, No, No, maybe?**

RAW, that doesn't work.  The text lays out the method to recharge the vial, and it involves putting your blood (and CON) in right then.  No alternate recharging method is offered.

RAI, it seems pretty clear that it doesn't work.  In particular, you're not even allowed to carry more than one charged Blood Reservoir at a time.  If they're explicitly preventing you from using the version where you buy multiple copies of the same magic item, they probably don't want you to use the version where you're just ponying up for a few glass vials either.

Simulationist, it doesn't work.  Without anticoagulants, blood left out in the open clots fully in a matter of an hour or two.  Worth noting as well that removing that quantity of blood doesn't necessarily cause that kind of con damage in other cases - the con damage may well be as a result of direct stat-draining effects from the item.

So... no.

On the bright side, there is still a sort-of workaround.  You can only use vials that are charged with your own blood, and you can only carry one charged vial at a time, but if you can get your buddies to each carry a vial of your blood for you (which they can't use), you can swap out with them at appropriate times.  That's still a bit cheesy, but it at least works by RAW.

Comment: This is a pretty reasonable answer, but I would point out that these vials aren’t *quite* the same as having multiple *blood reservoirs*. This way, you still need to stop and take the time to transfer blood from a vial to the *blood reservoir*, as opposed to simply having more charges waiting around if you could have multiple *blood reservoirs*. A full minute could easily be more valuable/costly than 4 Constitution damage in some cases. So your case for the authors’ intent is pretty strong, but it *is* possible they could see this as acceptable even where multiple *blood reservoirs* is not.

Comment: @KRyan when we're looking at RAI, we have to try to intuit what the devs are thinking.  In this case, they specifically disallowed the most obvious case of carrying extra charges with a special rule.  To me, that's a pretty clear indicator of how they wanted the item to be used or not used.  The fact that they didn't happen to address some less-obvious case doesn't really provide further information one way or the other.  I'm pretty sure by extension that my workaround also isn't RAI, but it is RAW.

Comment: If you had asserted that your workaround wasn’t RAI in your answer, I would downvote it. You should be very, *very* careful about asserting the authors’ intent—that’s putting words in their mouth, and that is something you should only do when you can really conclusively back it up. You have a pretty strong case for the place you actually do assert RAI in your answer, so I’ve held off on downvoting for that, but it still *is* purely circumstantial and I can think of at least one reasonable alternative for how the authors might think about this idea.

Comment: @KRyan fair.  I've adjusted my second paragraph to reflect my own level of certainty, rather than attempting to state with authority what RAI is.

Comment: I cant say I fully agree with the wording of RAW ether. Nothing of a ritual is mentioned. It simply states "Filling the vial takes a full minute. Doing so causes 4 Con damage to yourself." Which can be interpreted as a special magical ritual sure. But can easily be interpreted as slitting your wrist and bleeding out a large amount of blood, leaving you weak and tired. Several other items with blood loss effects cause similar con damage. Im not saying its wrong. Just poorly backed up.

Comment: That’s a solid edit, cheers for that. I think that does improve the answer in a small but meaningful way.

Comment: @Erudaki fair.  I have removed reference to "ritual", replaced with "method".

Comment: I'd also point out that it specifies that the blood in the vial is prevented from clotting and coagulating... which seems to *imply* (to me, anyway) that it needs to be fresh blood.

Comment: @I agree Ifusaso, but if thats the only requirement your putting on it, a Gentle Repose spell to preserve the blood would allow you to get around that. Or better yet. A bag of Corpse Ferrying full of blood vials would all be "Fresh"

Answer (score 4):

It seems reasonable, but no rule says you can do that.

There are no rules for filling some other vial with blood; nothing that says you take the same Constitution damage, certainly nothing that allows you to store it for any length of time. Likewise, the single written way to fill the *blood reservoir* is directly from your body, taking Constitution damage; nothing is written about filling it from any other vial. Magic items work a specific way, the way they are written, and any other functionality or usage is going to be purely up to the GM.

So you’ll have to ask your GM. I think it seems reasonable; I would allow it. But your GM may disagree. He or she might point out that this way allows you to fill a bunch of vials, taking a bunch of Constitution damage, and then heal it all with a single *restoration*, where if you had to fill a vial and use it before you could fill it again, you would probably want to use a *restoration* for each filling, so this way saves you spell slots or wand charges or whatever. I don’t think that’s a huge deal but your GM might.